# How to filter dataframe from string variable

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I know i can filter a dataframe using this command:

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-c(2,1,2)
c<-c(3,1,1)
test<-data.frame(a,b,c)
test2<-subset(test,a>1&b>1)
```

which will return (3,2,1), the thing is that a have the filter conditions in a string:

```
filt<-"a>1&b>1"
```

is there a way i can filter using this variable? like `subset(test,filt)`

i tried `subset(test,eval(filt))` but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
subset(test, eval(parse(text = filt)))
```